# WPF DataGrid binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I came across an issue when a IList is bound to a datagrid.

The class structure is,

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual SalesLine SalesLine { get; set; }
    public virtual int Precedence { get; set; }
}

public class SalesLine
{
    public virtual int SalesLineID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual SalesPerson SalesPerson { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

I create a new IList of Customer class.

```
IList<Customer> customerList = new IList<Customer>();
```

Then the "customerList" is populated.
Since customer has a SalesLine the "salesLines" IList is populated with all sales lines in the database.

Now with following XAML I am going to bind the customerList to the datagrid,

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                  Name="grdCustomers" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}" CanUserAddRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="250" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address Street" Binding="{Binding AddressLine1}" Width="150" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address Town" Binding="{Binding AddressLine2}" Width="150" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address Area" Binding="{Binding AddressLine3}" Width="150" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is Active" Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Width="75" />
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Sales Line"  Width="150"
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding  SalesLine}"
                        SelectedValuePath="SalesLineID"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name">
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.SalesLineList}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.SalesLineList}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Now it properly display all the columns except the sales line column.

Even though I have bound the SalesLine to the column, it does not display the current rows sales line name in the grid. However, when I click on the dropdown box, the dropdown is populated.

Please help me displaying the sales line name on the sales line column.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the `Customer.SalesLine` property does not point to an object in `SalesLineList`

You need to overwrite the `ToString()` method in the `SalesLine` class to make two objects be the same if their IDs match. By default, it will only consider them the same if they reference the exact same object in memoroy.